# Need to get stuck into a local optima in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I need to get stuck in a local optima in a feed forward neural network. I need an example and an initialization of weights with which using steepest gradient descent will get stuck in a local optima (within a certain boundary weights for each dimension). I can't find such an example, atleast it seems so, and therefore cannot test a new algorithm.

Can anyone point to some documents, resources, or provide me an example how to get stuck in local optima.

Comment: You know you need at least two non-linear layers to make the error function non-convex, right? Also, some people speculate that during training ANNs *plateaus* are more often the problem than local minima.

Comment: @RomanShapovalov: Can you give reference that one needs more than one nonlinear hidden layer to make the surface non-convex? What I know is we need atleast one hidden layer to make the error surface non-convex. Ya i am getting into regions which seems like a plateau, but i need to get an example to get stuck to check a modification of an algorithm.

Comment: I guess you are right, the top layer may be linear as long as the hidden layer is not. I’ll try to think of an example.

Comment: I  have the hidden as well as the output layer using sigmoid threshold.

Answer (score 4):

Lets analyzse what "getting stuck in local optima" means. Have a look at the [SARPROP paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.8197&rep=rep1&type=pdf). SARPROP is a learning algorithm for feed-forward neural networks which exactly has the goal to avoid getting stuck in local optima. Have a look at Figure 1 on page 3 of the linked document. It shows the error surface regarding **one single weight**. During early steps of training, this error surface will alter quickly. But as soon as the algorithm gets closer to convergence, this error surface regarding one weight will stabilze. Now, you are stuck in a local optimum regarding a certain weight, if your learning algorithm is not able to "push" the weight over a "hill" to reach a better optimum. SARPROP tries to solve this by adding positive noise to the weight update involved in original RPROP. So the algorithm has a chance to be pushed out of such "valleys".

Now, to construct the convergence in local optima, you should calculate a set of random weights which stay fixed in the following. Now use a learning algorithm which is known to quickly converge in local optima, like RPROP. Then use the same weight initializations and apply SARPROP or your new algorithm. Then compare e.g. the Root Mean Squared Error on your training data as soon the network has converged. Do this with some hundreds of weight initializations and apply statistics.

Comment: I am using simple backpropagation to train small networks on XOR and some other well known datasets. Till now the training time were long and I could not find any evidence of the new algorithm to get better results in some cases which it should. So, my question was, if there was some specific case which I can reproduce to get stuck in the local minima.